# Error: Pandas requires version '0.13.0' or newer of 'pyarrow' (version '0.11.1' currently installed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to use pyarrow to read parquet files. However, I cannot seem to download pyarrow. I've tried:

`pip install pyarrow` 
`pip3 install pyarrow` 
`pip install -m pyarrow`

and none of the commands worked.

I then proceeded to try using

`conda install pyarrow`

Which got pyarrow 0.11.0 to work however when I tried running my file I would get the following error:

Pandas requires version '0.13.0' or newer of 'pyarrow' (version '0.11.1' currently installed).

I've tried updating the version but it did not seem to resolve anything.

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade pyarrow`?

Comment: Didn't work. For some reason, I cannot get it downloaded with pip either.

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?